# Bootstrap - 2 List Columns in 1 Panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, list, panel

So I have a panel with a list-group inside.

I can trying to get it to display in 2 columns without html change. I just want to code the page one item after another in one long list then have css break it apart into 2 columns on large media over 768.

Right now I added a width: 50% to the list-group-item, but it make the entire list 50%, it won't push even ones to the right.

http://www.bootply.com/WElVzZr6pO

Is this a correct way of doing this, or is there a better way for something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this http://www.bootply.com/6LTURNp6Fq. Add "col-xs-6" along with "list-group-item", like,

```
<div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Mobile Phones <span class="badge">Check Balance</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Laptops &amp; Desktops <span class="badge">Check Balance</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Mobile Phones <span class="badge">Check Balance</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Laptops &amp; Desktops <span class="badge">Check Balance</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Mobile Phones <span class="badge">Check Balance</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Laptops &amp; Desktops <span class="badge">Check Balance</span></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't invent the wheel, may want to use Grid instead
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/
You can use  `.col-xs-6` as class for your left and right sides (for mobile and desktop.)

I hope that helps.